# Query is not returning the data fully in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor 5.2.2 .Iam using a query to fetch the data from DB in my BeforeAll function.If the query returns a table of below 100 rows,then I am able to get the full data,but if the table rows are more or above 100, the query is not picking the full data.It is returning some of the first rows.Actually, it should fetch all data,but not fetching fully.Why it's behave like this?Any idea?.Code in the BeforeAll function is given below.And i am getting the data in array post_details and using it in a for loop.

```
var post_details=[];
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('tedious').Request;

var config = 
 {
  userName: 'xxx', 
  password: 'xxxx', 
  server: 'xxxxx', 
  options: 
    {
       database: 'xxx' ,
       encrypt: true,
       rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion: true
    }
  }
 var connection = new Connection(config);

BeforeAll(function () {  

    connection.on('connect', function(err) {
      if (err){
        console.log(err);
      }
  else{
    request = new Request("select * from company",function(err,rowCount, rows) {  

       });
    request.on('row', function(columns) {
        var row={};
        columns.forEach(function(column) {
            row[column.metadata.colName] = column.value;
        });
        post_details.push(row);
    });
    connection.execSql(request);
  }                    
});
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may have to provide more details like Query and library you are using using to get data from db + supporting code ...

Comment: I have added more details.